# convert a string year into a date object

Tags: apex

I have a requiremnet, where I have given a year of type `string`.  I want to convert it into  `date object` and add Year, month and days to above date instance.

```
String callYear = '2014';
```

Now my requirent is If callYear is '2014' then new `date` instance must be 15th September of previous year.

Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A String can be converted into an Integer using [Integer.valueOf](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_integer.htm#apex_System_Integer_valueOf). Here is an example of how to do that:

```
String callYear = '2014';
Integer year = Integer.valueOf(callYear);
```

Once it's an Integer you can convert it to a [Date](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm) by using [Date.newInstance](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_newInstance):

```
Date myDate = Date.newInstance((year - 1), 9, 15);
```